# Partial differential equation using chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

A function $u$ of two variables is defined implicitly by $u(x,t)=f(x-tu(x,t))$,
where f is a given bounded, differentiable function of one variable, $f : R → R$.

Q:Given that $f(s)=1−\tanh s$,find the smallest positive number $t_m$ such that $\cfrac{∂u}{∂x}$ is undefined for precisely one value of $x$.

I found that $\cfrac{∂u}{∂x} = \cfrac{ f′(x−tu(x,t))}{1+tf′(x−tu(x,t))}$
but have no idea on what to do next.

Comment: In this case, f(x)= tanh(x) so f'(x)= 1- tanh^2(x).  Put those into your fraction.

Comment: ... and ensure that the denominator in $\partial_x u$ does not vanish.